# Encontrar el rango mas grande en un array

Tags: ruby

me surgió un problema al intentar hacer que de un array (de x cantidad de números) me saque el rango mas grande que haya. Lo que sucede es que no me entra por algún motivo a un if (supongo que es algo que tiene que ver con mi proceso de lógica) Lo plantee. (Esta es la primera vez que uso stackoverflow, así que lo siento por errores que puedan haber)

```
def larRang(varray)
    bestRange = []
    longestLenght = 0
    nums = {}
    for num  in varray do
        puts"punto de control 1"
        nums[num] = true
    end
    for num in varray do
        puts"punto de control 2"
        if not nums[num]
            next
        end
        nums[num] = false
        currentLenght = 1
        left = num - 1
        right = num + 1
        while nums.include?(left)
            puts"punto de control 3"
            nums[left] = false
            currentLenght += 1
            left -= 1
        end
        while nums.include?(right)
            puts"punto de control 4"
            nums[right] = false
            currentLenght += 1
            left += 1
        end
    end
        #Por alguna razon no esta entrando al if
    if currentLenght > longestLenght
            puts"Hola"
            longestLenght = currentLenght
            bestRange = [left + 1, right - 1]
    else
    puts"No funciona"
    end
    puts bestRange
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al ejecutar el código se quedó en un bucle infinito imprimiendo "punto de control 4"

Algunas notas:

- falta un `end` al final

Digamos que tenemos el arreglo `[1, 2, 3]`
Cuando comienzas el programa, estás creando un hash `nums` cuyo valor es

```rb
{ 1 => true, 2 => true, 3 => true }
```

Luego seteas el primer elemento a `false` y buscas por `0` que da `false` así que no entra al "punto de control 3"
y luego, buscar por `2` que da `true`, seteas el valor de ese elemento a `false`, cambias el valor de `left` a `1` y sigues buscando por `2` -- bucle infinito

Cambiando `left += 1` por `right += 1` solventas ese problema.

Ahora, estás usando `nums.include?(foo)` lo que hace ese código es buscar un elemento cuyo "key" sea "foo", no importa el valor que tenga ese key por lo que estás recorriendo muchas veces los mismos números/rangos, cambiándolo por `nums[foo]` o sea `nums[left]` o `nums[right]` eliminaría ese problema.

El código no es muy "rubbish" es decir no utiliza las características del lenguaje, te recomiendo revisar cosas como `sort`, `uniq`, `each_cons` que puede que te ayuden a resolver el problema de una forma diferente sin hacer múltiples búsquedas en el array o el hash

```
varray.sort.uniq.each_cons(2) do |i, j|
  puts "i: #{i} - j: #{j}"
end
```